# Image_style_url with [default_image]

Tags: media

I am trying to print a commentator's avatar picture in the comments.tpl.php

```
<img src="
        <?php
            if ($picture) {
                print image_style_url('comment_picture', $comment->picture->uri);
                ?>"</img>
```

which works as desired. However it doesn't post the default_picture if the user does not have a profile picture uploaded.

I've tried using [default_image] but then nothing happens

```
<img src="
        <?php
            if ($picture) {
                print image_style_url('comment_picture', $comment->picture->uri);
             } else {
                print image_style_url('comment_picture', [default_image]);
            }
                ?>"</img>
```

Comment: What is `[default_image]`? No such thing in HTML. If you don't want to give us real URL, use example.com domain as placeholder. Also, have you tried to `kpr($picture)`? Quite possible it's something that does not bool cast to `FALSE`.

Comment: According to various sniplets, ['default_image'] does exist Molot and is referenced in multiple drupal discussions (example: https://drupal.org/node/1439136 )

In this particular case ['default_image'] should be pointed toward the default uploaded avatar.

Comment: `$fields['user-user-field_user_picture']['field_config']['settings']['default_image']` exists, but it does not mean you can just go and write `[default_image]` wherever you want. First, it's not even valid PHP, as string constants should be in parenthesis, and second, giving only index, without an array, is like asking for third - without specifying if you want third pencil or third guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in else condition...

```
$user = user_load($comment->uid);
print theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user));
```

OR

```
$filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
$default_image = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $style, 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => '', 'title' => ''));
print $default_image;
```

Comment: How would one go about plugging the default image into the image_style?

Comment: Updated answer..